# Covariance of not linearly dependent variablies

Tags: random-variables, expectation, covariance

*X ~ U(−1,1)*, $Y=SX$. Where $S$ is a random variable, with probability density function $p(s=1)=0.5$ and $p(s=-1)=0.5$.

*Are my calculations of $Cov(X, Y)$ correct? Does $ E(X) = 0 \implies E(X^2) = 0$? How to calculate $E(XS), if \,\, E(X) \neq 0 \,\, and \,\, E(S) \neq 0$*

Probability density function for *X ~ U(−1,1)*:
$$
p(x) = 1, x \in [-1, 1]
\\[1ex]
p(x) = 0, x \notin [-1, 1] \tag{1}\label{1} 
\\[1ex]
U(a,b) = \frac{1}{b - a}, \,where \,\,b > a
\\[1ex]
X = U(-1, 1) = \frac{1}{1 - (-1)} = \frac{1}{2}
$$

Expectation for X equals:
$$
E(X) = \int_{-1}^1U(-1,1)p(x)dx \stackrel{\eqref{1}}= \int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{1 - (-1)}p(x)dx = \int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{2}dx = 0 \tag{2}\label{2} 
$$

Expectation for S equals:
$$
E(S) = \sum_{i=1}^2p(s)s_i = \frac{1}{2}(-1) + \frac{1}{2}(1) = 0 \tag{3}\label{3} 
$$

Due to $x$ and $s$ are independent:
$$
E(XS) = E(X)E(S) = 0 \tag{4}\label{4} 
$$

Covariance:
$$
Cov (X, Y) = E\Bigl(\bigl(X - E(X)\bigr) * \bigl(XS - E(XS)\bigr)\Bigr) \stackrel{\eqref{2}} =
\\[1ex]
= E\Bigl(X \bigl(XS - E(XS)\bigr)\Bigr) \stackrel{\eqref{4}}= E\bigl(X(XS - 0)\bigr) = 
\\[1ex] 
= E(X^2S) \stackrel{\eqref{4}}= E(X^2)E(S) \stackrel{\eqref{3}}= E(X^2) * 0 = 0.
$$

Comment: How do you know that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables? And in general $E(X) = 0 \not \implies E(X^2) = 0$,take for example $X\sim N(0,1) $

Comment: @user190080 $X$ and $Y$ are NOT independent. $X$ and $S$ are independent. $X$ and $Y$ aren't linearly dependent

Comment: Sorry, typo, I meant $X$ and $S$ - if they are independent, then you might want to add this to your assumptions, I can't see any mentioning of it.

Comment: @user190080 here is definition of both: $X ~ U(−1,1)$, whereas $S$ is a random variable, with probability density function $p(s=1)=0.5$ and $p(s=−1)=0.5$. From definition you can conclude they are independent

Comment: actually you can't infer this by your definitions....just put $S=sign(X)$ and you have your Bernoulli variable expressed by $X$

Comment: @user190080 Yes, $S$ is a Bernoulli distribution

Comment: It is...but what I wanted to clarify is, that with what is stated in your first lines you can not conclude that $S$ and $X$ are actually independent, so you need to be careful while calculating $E(XS)$ for example.

Comment: @user190080 wow! Could you please explain how $X$ and $S$ could be linearly dependent if *X ~ U(-1,1)* and *S* is a Bernoulliu distribution?

Comment: I did in my third comment. You could consider to ask another question concerning this specific issue and link this one to it, just to detangle the problem a bit.